# Get Image from UserControl - Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Right now i'm using [ImageTools](http://imagetools.codeplex.com) to load the image into a pdf using [SilverPDF](http://silverpdf.codeplex.com/), the image that i'm loading is from the current LayoutGrid, however, i want to get the image from another user control, without navigating to it.  First i thought that it would be as easy as Creating an instance of that user control and get into it's LayoutRoot property but that is not rendering correctly into the pdf (i get the controls overlaped) is there a way to "render" the control "in memory" without actually loading into the window?, any help is highly appreciated.

PD, the versions that i'm currently working are:
.NET Framework 4.0,
Silverlight 4.0 &
C#

-Regards

Comment: that usercontrol have parent. I want to say usercontrol in VisualTree?

Comment: No, is instantiated in memoery E.G.   MyUserControl control = new MyUserControl(initializationVariables)

Comment: usercontrol must be in visual tree. must has parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usercontrol must be in visual tree.

you can add in LayoutGrid, take  necessary for pdf  and remove from LayoutGrid.

Comment: i'll try this solution, i was actually trying to avoid this approach as i don't want to show/hide what i'm about to capture

Comment: Yeap, i ended up adding the the elements into the UserControl then play with the visibility and Dimensions, taking the snapshot and then collapsing it again, the good news is that it happends fast so no UI alteration detected so far.  Thanks!